# Eclipse plug in developement (JDT): Surround if statement with braces

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

It is possible to define an if-else in one line statement.

```
if (isFormed)
        if (i == 1)
            System.out.println("i is 1");
        else
            System.out.println("i is undefined");
```

I need to surround one line if statements with braces using my eclipse plugin.

This is what I tried

```
node.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean visit(IfStatement ifStatement) {
                        //Add Block in case of IfStatemnet if it is not there.
                        if(ifStatement != null){
                            Statement thenStatement = ifStatement.getThenStatement();
                            Statement elseStatement = ifStatement.getElseStatement();
                            String codeToReplace = "if("+ifStatement.getExpression()+")";
                            if(thenStatement instanceof Block)
                                codeToReplace += "\n"+ thenStatement + "";
                            else
                                codeToReplace += "{\n"+ thenStatement + "\n}";
                            if(elseStatement != null){
                                if(elseStatement instanceof Block)
                                    codeToReplace += "else" + elseStatement +"\n";
                                else
                                    codeToReplace += "else{\n" + elseStatement +"\n}";
                            }
                            replaceStatment(rewriter, getBlockInstence(ifStatement), codeToReplace , ifStatement);
                        }
                        return super.visit(ifStatement);
                    }
                });
```

This works for outer if, but doesn't work with inner if/else.

P.S.: There's a way to do this using formatter in preferences. I have to make this part of my plugin.

Comment: It seems to me as if you might be overwriting your own replacements. If you create new Code in AST I would recommend to  use the AST.new* factory methods instead of String concatenation. This will create objects you can add to the AST model.

Comment: I'd just like to recommend you to thoroughly think about the impact of such a change. Plugins that tell me how I have to design my code are unlikely to stay in my IDE for long. The way Frederik recommended seems to me more appealing, but even then I'd recommend you to not change anyones Preferences without telling them what you did.

Comment: Thanks for responding. We understand what you are saying and we do get confirmation from user before making any preference or code changes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative way to do this. Open preferences in Eclipse, go to **Java -> Editor -> Save actions**. Enable save actions, then click on **Configure**. Go to Code Styles tab, then enable the option under Control Statements.

This will perform the action you want everytime the file is being saved.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is correct but I need to make this part of plugin. We don't want user to do any kind of configurations.

Comment: Export preferences to a file, then add it as a customization file. Search for "plugin_customization.ini" and you will find alot of information. This way this setting will be set by default.